# React view not successfully listening to store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have [a React controller-view](https://github.com/chadoh/life/pull/6/files#diff-8604f489b9796fbf13573d18b7b72eb4R18) that subscribes to two different stores, and initiates calls that will cause each of them to emit:

```
componentWillMount() {
  UserStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  EventStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
}

componentDidMount() {
  UserService.getUser(this.props.params.slug)
  EventService.fetchEventsForUser(this.props.params.slug);
}
```

For the `UserStore` listener, this works fine. The user is fetched from the API, which comes back to [the `UserStore`](https://github.com/chadoh/life/pull/6/files#diff-0922143789ebab05613ef9f3a0303c70R7), which emits a change. If I put `console.log` statements in, I can see all of this flow in exactly the way I'd expect, ending in the `_onChange` function of my controller-view.

**But.** For some inexplicable reason, the change listener added to [the `EventStore`](https://github.com/chadoh/life/pull/6/files#diff-e3943b8df1283906a2c496e3f22aace5R5) isn't firing. The events are correctly fetched from the API, and which come back to the `EventStore` method that I expect, which correctly updates `EventStore`'s internal state, and it even fires `emitChange()` just fine (I've verified with copious `console.log` statements). But `_onChange` in the controller-view is never called!

I've been trying to troubleshoot this for close to double-digit hours now. I don't feel any closer to an answer than when I started. I don't even know where to look.

---

#### Other notes

- I tried removing the `UserStore` listener from my controller-view, just setting static content in `UserStore`. I thought maybe there could be a race condition between the two updating. Nothing changed.
- I tried splitting my controller-view's `_onChange` into two separate functions, again with the suspicion that they weren't playing nicely together. But the `console.log`s showed that `_onUserChange` was called as expected, but `_onEventChange` was never called at all.
- **This used to work!** In the master branch, which the pull request I've been linking to branches from, it works! Everything's structured a bit differently, there—the controller-view I've been linking to only listens to changes in `UserStore`, while its child component listens for changes in `EventStore`. If I duplicate this structure, though, it still doesn't work. In my new branch, whatever component is listening to changes in `EventStore` seems to be completely deaf to such changes.
- Also on `master`, `EventStore` did much more computation than it does now. I very much doubt that it being slow would make its listeners more likely to hear it, though. `UserStore` is equivalently simple, and its listeners have no problem hearing it.
- **Sometimes it *does* work.** About 1 page load in 100, it works. The component updates its state, and the server-loaded content actually displays. I haven't been able to reproduce this or determine what causes it.
- [Another component in this app](https://github.com/chadoh/life/pull/6/files#diff-0265e467b11d169edb0baaa297741de8R23) also listens for `EventStore` changes, and also rarely hears them.
- You can see it failing to work at http://life.chadoh.com/#/chadoh. If you then visit http://life.chadoh.com/#/chadoh/week/0, you'll see that an event has correctly been loaded from the server. But for some reason the listeners were not alerted. If you refresh the page on http://life.chadoh.com/#/chadoh/week/0, the sidebar will never be updated with events (the difference is whether it's initially rendered before or after `EventStore` has already been loaded with data).
- Changing the `get events()` method in `EventStore` to a regular `events()` has no effect.
- Putting the `EventService.fetchEvents` call inside a `setTimeout` does not yield better results.
- Putting the `listen` calls inside the constructor does not yield better results.

Comment: Could it be caching causing something to run synchronously? I would add the `addChangeListener` calls to *before* both the service calls.

Comment: Thanks @BinaryMuse. I should have mentioned that I've also tried that. To no avail. :-(   When I first tried it just now, two out of three page loads actually worked! But then I refreshed another dozen times, and it never loads. _le sigh_

Comment: Have you tried switching the order in which these statements appear? If EventService is really an action creator, you could very well be in a situation in which the action event is being raised before the store is ready to respond to it. Worth a try switching the order.

Comment: @HalHelms please see the previous comments. Yes, I tried that.

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect the change that you both suggested. Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. 

Comment: Hmm when I visit http://life.chadoh.com/#/chadoh I think I always get a lot of a's printed with dates on them that seem to have come back from a network request. What am I supposed to be seeing?

Comment: @noveyak hmm, it appears I have encoding problems. I'll look into that. Those should be `●`, not `ã–`. But no, that's not the network-loaded data. That's a loading screen. Once it actually notices the network request, it will look a bit like http://brittanyforks.com/life/, with emojis (assuming I fix encoding issues) all down the left-most column.

Comment: @noveyak I believe the encoding issue is fixed. The component still never updates after the data comes back from the server.

Comment: I know that the examples given by Facebook show the code working when componentDidUpdate is called, but I've run into problems with that. Although my problems were different than yours, I found putting code in componentWillUpdate solved my problem.

Comment: @HalHelms hmm... I don't think I'm ever using `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: Uggh -- I'm sorry. I'm being slow today. I meant componentWillMount.

Comment: @HalHelms thanks for the suggestion! I tried moving the shown code to `componentWillMount`, but it only listened correctly the first time I loaded the page. I also tried putting the `addChangeListener` calls in `componentWillMount` and the `Service` calls in `componentDidMount`. This also didn't work. Which, I mean, I'm sort of glad? That wouldn't make sense. The listener for the `UserStore` actually listens ***every single time***. The listener for `EventStore` actually listens about ***1 in 100***. What's the difference??

Comment: @HalHelms I also tried adding the `listen` calls to the constructor. It worked three out of four times on the first four reloads, and then not again for another ten.

Comment: Which Flux library are you using? Or more specifically, what pub/sub lib is used for `emitChange` and `listen`?

Comment: @HannesJohansson good question! I am using Facebook's `flux` library, version `2.0.3`. https://github.com/chadoh/life/blob/no-dates/package.json#L40

Comment: I got curious and cloned your GitHub repo. After commenting out a bunch of code, I get `_onChange` to execute for both stores consistently, without failure. `EventService` and `UserService` both now just immediately returns a dummy object (and the stores don't update any state, they just immediately fire `emitChange`). I also removed the whole authentication route, so I only kept the "user" route for testing. As I said, it works.

Comment: I really can't see any reason why it wouldn't work. But if you're really sure that the store gets the dispatched action and really executes `emitChange`, then it simply has to be something about EventEmitter that's not behaving as expected. Not the Flux dispatcher, and not even the async API calls. I don't see any other explanation.

Comment: @HannesJohansson thank you so much for doing all of that! If you undo all of your commenting-out and put `console.log` statements in `EventStore`'s `_registerToActions` and in `BaseStore`'s `emitChange`, you can double-check me on those things. I agree, it seems like it could be a subtle bug in `EventEmitter`. Which of your changes do you think could have caused it to work? Removing routes? Maybe I'll start down the same path, until I find the piece that breaks it.

Comment: I really don't know. I tried now to fake the API with `setTimeout` to get async behavior, still worked. Tried adding back the `AuthenticatedApp` root route, still worked. If I were you I would add a breakpoint in `BaseStore`'s `emitChange` and check if your `onChange` callback is actually in `this.listeners('CHANGE')`. If it isn't, something has unregistered the callback from the `EventEmitter` before it had a chance to run. If it is, I don't know, step into `EventEmitter`'s code and find the bug I guess.

Comment: @HannesJohansson you didn't have to undo the async behavior, because it makes ajax requests to a Heroku app that should work for you, too. Thank you for all of this. I'll dig in again this afternoon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see `EventsStore` extends `BaseStore` which extends `events.EventEmitter`. Is that the node.js standard library event emitter?

If so, you may have a naming conflict on `_events`.

Your store uses `_events` to hold data: https://github.com/chadoh/life/blob/no-dates/src/stores/EventStore.js#L10

But `EventEmitter` also uses `_events` to store event handlers: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/d13d7f74d794340ac5e126cfb4ce507fe0f803d5/lib/events.js#L140-L186

As a result, event data may overwrite the collection of event handlers, causing handlers to never fire (because they aren't there!).

You could try using a different key to hold data (eg `_eventData`) and see if that solves your problem!

Comment: That was it! I actually decided to go with the [`alt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alt) variant of Flux, which avoids the problem and, sadly, makes all of your links point to irrelevant things. But I've created a separate pull request with [your suggested fix](https://github.com/chadoh/life/commit/c25ac1ecf1e66e3934bc8e714a0ff91a109887ff) as a historic record. Great find!!